# Selenium IE WebDriver doesn't close/quit after test

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am running selenium test for IE11, but after test it doesn't close IE even though I used quit() or close(). My code is below:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\selenium\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
        caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        //test steps
        driver.quit();
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not resetting driver to some another during your test steps?

Comment: @VishalJagtap: hi, I am sure I don't reset anything. Test steps work on FF and Chrome, and it closes them browsers. But when I switched to IE, test steps also work, but it doesn't close IE windows after test

Answer (score 2):

> - On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the
>   Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value
>   can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the
>   Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools
>   menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a
>   check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
> - Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and
>   higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet
>   Options dialog.
> - The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the
>   native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
> - For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
>   computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
>   of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the
>   key you must examine in the registry editor is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
>   installations, the key is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
>   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
>   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
>   DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem for IE11.
all tests worked fine on chrome but when switch to IE it failed on closing the windows.
u may have same issue:
i'm closing the windows using the "@AfterMethod" and then close it.
the problem was when trying to take screenshots or browserConsole in IE.
it works different in this browser.
try to remove it (only for checking).

for my framework it worked and solved this problem.

Comment: You're right, All tests ran fine on FF and Chrome, but when I switched to IE, the test steps also ran, but just couldn't close window after test. I also try this: @After
    public void quitDriver()
    {
        webDriver.quit();
    } but it doesn't work